# Generate dataframe using Gauss law

Tags: python, pandas, random, timestamp, gauss

I would like to generate a dataframe. In this dataframe, the column "Date" using the timestamp has to be randomly generated. **I would like to generate it using the gauss-law**. I know the function random.gauss() and I have this code :

```py
from faker import Faker
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta

fake_parking = [
    {'Licence Plate':fake.license_plate(), 
     'Start_date':fake.date_time_between_dates(datetime_start='-2y', datetime_end='-1d'),
     'Duration':fake.time_delta(end_datetime='+30d')
    } for x in range(10000)]
df = pd.DataFrame(fake_parking)
```

[Here, I generate random date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JnBw.png) and I would like that these dates are generated featuring [the gauss-law](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZa4u.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that the dataframe that one wants to generate has three columns:`LicensePlate`, `Start Date` and `Duration`, one can do the following

```
import pandas as pd
import random 
import datetime as dt
import faker

fake = faker.Faker()
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'LicensePlate': [fake.license_plate() for i in range(100)],
    'Start Date': [dt.datetime.now() + dt.timedelta(seconds=random.gauss(0, 1000)) for i in range(100)],
    'Duration': [dt.timedelta(seconds=random.gauss(0, 1000)) for i in range(100)]
})

[Out]:

   LicensePlate                 Start Date                 Duration
0       XV 5129 2022-10-18 12:59:29.287650   0 days 00:24:58.640538
1      91-60124 2022-10-18 13:21:41.058608 -1 days +23:43:29.201520
2        733TBH 2022-10-18 13:26:30.057752 -1 days +23:43:59.308018
3       955 YJB 2022-10-18 13:48:31.069223   0 days 00:08:14.982752
4       0-82573 2022-10-18 13:00:43.735401   0 days 00:02:33.887666
..          ...                        ...                      ...
95      MHS 812 2022-10-18 13:29:13.169237   0 days 00:12:18.462455
96      D66-19E 2022-10-18 13:22:49.714652 -1 days +23:42:44.846897
97      SGW 257 2022-10-18 13:12:32.425996 -1 days +23:47:04.114940
98      K16-80P 2022-10-18 13:42:09.283379 -1 days +23:39:17.864417
99     28-83111 2022-10-18 13:03:26.028862   0 days 00:03:46.996096
```

**Notes:**

- One is using [`faker`](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to generate fake license plates.
- To make sure it follows a Normal/Gaussian distribution, one is using [`random.gauss`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.gauss). One can adjust the mean and standard deviation accordingly.